# Linux: Behaviour of mmap() when swap disabled

Tags: linux, mmap, virtual-memory

Assume that I disabled the Linux page swapping so that no pages are stored in disk's swap partition. But I still can map a file say `data.bin` using mmap().

Do this file get updated into disk, when the corresponding mapped memory is modified ?

Answer (score 0):

A memory mapped file could only end up in the swap file, in case of it is mapped privately (MAP_PRIVATE) -- in this case changes are not propagated to the mapped file.